# this method cant delete what is its error

Tags: vue.js

```js
async onDeleteProduct(id, index){
  try{
    const result = await this.$axios.$delete('http://localhost:8000/api/products'+id)
    if(result.status){
      this.products.splice(index, 1)
    }
  } catch(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
},
```

Comment: As per your code you are handling delete operation at both sides (API as well as client side). Which one is not working ? Also, can you please share the error you are getting.

Comment: Hi, please put in more effort and explanation as of what is not working here.

Comment: When i call the methode in a button, it doesnt delete.